# How do I corrupt an .exe for testing

Tags: tools

I need to run a test which requires that I corrupt a specific .exe file.  For security reasons I cannot upload this file to http://corrupt-a-file.net/.  Is there a known tool for Windows that I can use, or a recommended technique?

Comment: Bit off-topic as your question is about corrupting files, not really about testing.

Comment: Might be off topic, but... are you sure this external service is not injecting a virus?

Comment: @NielsvanReijmersdal, not that off-topic, it looks like setting up test data. Still I'm curious what kind of test is that.

Comment: @Niels thanks for your answer, the hex editor was the key.

Comment: @dzieciou - as for the test type, our software has some neat fail overs. I needed a quick way to corrupt an aspect of the software to trigger an event which in turn would replace the bad file(s).  Greatly appreciate the help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If we define corrupt as not being able to start the executable, just open it with a text editor (like [notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/)) and change some text around and save. Some executables might be to large to open, but I think a good text-editor should be able to handle most. Open the executable, if it still works, change more text around :)

The smallest changes will often result in a broken application.

Maybe have a look at the file with a [hexeditor](http://mh-nexus.de/en/hxd/) and change some of the important bits.

Comment: For big files this can be done simply in command line through file concatenation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2477271/concatenate-text-files-with-windows-command-line-dropping-leading-lines